# A required certificate is not within its validity period: Microsoft Windows Certificate

Tags: windows-10, certificate

Today I tried to start taskmgr but it said the verified publisher is unknown. I checked the taskmgr's signature and detected that the Microsoft Windows certificate has expired and the file does not have a timestamp. mmc.exe is same. I started it but it gave me an error that an admin has blocked it. I checked its digital signature and saw the same error.
[image]

PS: No timestamp????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Microsoft Development PCA" certificates are used for **'beta' versions and Insider Preview builds.** The signatures aren't timestamped/countersigned because the entire build is usually marked to expire after a few months (e.g. `winver` says that build 18932 on my system expires on 2020-08), so there is no real need for signatures to outlast the intermediate CA.

Check the executable's version under "Properties" → "Details". Compare it to other (working) Windows components, and to the version shown in `winver` (or if that doesn't work, Explorer's "File" → "Help" → "About Windows", though it won't show all expiry information).